# Python: How do i store a text input from the user on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is what i tried so far to get the user's input:

```
master = Tk()
master.title('Title')

v = StringVar()

L1 = Label(master, text = 'Name')
L1.pack(side = LEFT)

E1 = Entry(master, textvariable = v, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

def userinput():
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    print a


b = Button(master, text = 'Submit', command = userinput)
b.pack(side = BOTTOM)


master.mainloop()
```

The real question is, how can i store the v.get() raw_input into a variable outside the function? Thx!

Comment: Is it even possible to pass a function like `v.get()` in `raw_input()` method?

Comment: @adil - Yes, because `v.get()` returns a string, which will then become the prompt for `raw_input`.

Comment: O yeah I got it....my bad never thought of that :)

Comment: Why do you use a GUI for some input, and raw_input for other input? That is highly unusual. If you're creating a GUI, you should never call raw_input. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I agree with [Bryan Oakley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global variable to hold the input:

```
inp = None
```

and then have your function update that variable:

```
def userinput():
    global inp
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    print a
    inp = a
```

So, your code will look like this:

```
master = Tk()
master.title('Title')

v = StringVar()

# Variable to hold the input
inp = None

L1 = Label(master, text = 'Name')
L1.pack(side = LEFT)

E1 = Entry(master, textvariable = v, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

def userinput():
    # Declare 'inp' to be global
    global inp
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    print a
    # Update the variable
    inp = a


b = Button(master, text = 'Submit', command = userinput)
b.pack(side = BOTTOM)


master.mainloop()
```

In the above code, `inp` will always be a fresh copy of the input which you can use elsewhere in the code.

However, it might be worthwhile to look into making your code a class.  That way, you can have a class attribute named `self.inp` and you won't have to do `global inp`.

Answer (score 0):

As others say - use `globe`

Example using class

```
from Tkinter import *

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.master.title('Title')

        self.v = StringVar()

        self.L1 = Label(self.master, text = 'Name')
        self.L1.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.E1 = Entry(self.master, textvariable = self.v, bd = 5)
        self.E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

        self.B1 = Button(self.master, text = 'Submit', command = self.userinput)
        self.B1.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        self.B2 = Button(self.master, text = 'Print', command = self.print_external_variable)
        self.B2.pack(side = TOP)

    #------------------

    def userinput(self):
        global external_variable

        external_variable = raw_input(self.v.get())
        #external_variable = self.v.get()

        print "inside - userinput:", external_variable

    #------------------

    def print_external_variable(self):
        # you don't need global if you don't change external_variable

        print "inside - print:", external_variable

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

external_variable = '- none -'

print "before run:", external_variable

master = Tk()
MainWindow(master)
master.mainloop()

print "after run:", external_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why using `raw_input` to take input when you can do the same with the `entry` widget?

There are few disadvantages of following the above practice:

- `raw_input` will cause the whole python interpreter to pause, but `entry` widget wont do that.
- `raw_input` can't be customized or it's bit hard to customize, but we can easily do that for `entry` widget.
- If you press the `button` again without entering data in `raw_input`, it will raise an error, but in `entry` widget it wont.

and for your problem's solution, there are 3 methods.

method 1:

- is to update the `textvariable` value, then you can access it using `v.get()`. (**Best**)

```
def userinput():
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    v.set(a)
# This would also cause an update in entry widget.
```

method 2:

- is to use `global` keyword inside the function and store the `raw_input`'s data to the global variable.

```
def userinput():
    global data
    data = raw_input(v.get())
```

method 3:

- is to update the `text` value of the button or entry box, then you can access it using `b.cget("text")`.
  (*changing text value is practically not useful, but still a method.*)

```
def userinput():
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    b.config(text=a)
```

I would suggest you to use method 1.

Answer (score -2):

Just make it return the User Input

```
def userinput():
    a = raw_input(v.get())
    return a
```

Then when you call it,you can do that by:

```
myvar=userinput()
```

Now,`myvar` contains the value of user input.

Comment: The Problem is that function is called whenever the button is clicked so how is this line `b = Button(master, text = 'Submit', command = userinput)` supposed to save some returned value can you explain.

I think as iCodez said its always better to make a class and set class variables to different values using the class functions (like userinput()).

Comment: Yep that would be the best approach.